# How to change font size of ttk::combobox

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I use ttk-widgets and want to change the fontsize of a ttk::combobox widget. As you can see in the example the fontsize of the label and the button change but not of the combobox.

```
font create MyFont -family Helvetica -size 12 -slant roman -weight normal
ttk::style theme use default
ttk::style configure TLabel -font MyFont
ttk::style configure TButton -font MyFont
ttk::style configure TCombobox -font MyFont

set Liste {Anton Berta Caesar}

ttk::label .lb -text "Label"
ttk::combobox .cb -values $Liste
ttk::button .bt -text "Change Fontsize" -command {font configure MyFont -size 20}

pack .lb .cb .bt
```

By the way there is the same problem with TMenubutton, ttk::entry and ttk::spinbox.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ttk::combobox widget's font is directly exposed as a widget option. Set it during creation (or with the `configure` method):

```
ttk::combobox .cb -values $Liste -font MyFont
```

To change the font used in the drop-down list, you need something rather more arcane (as it is using a traditional Tk listbox inside itself instead of something styled) *before* you create the combobox (or rather before you pop it down the first time, but that's tricky) because the option “database” is only read during widget creation in Tk:

```
option add *ComboboxPopdown.f.l.font MyFont
```

That `*ComboboxPopdown.f.l.font` is the arcane part. The `*ComboboxPopdown` says to affect all widgets that have a class of `ComboboxPopdown` (which is the class of the temporary popdown dialog created by the combobox bindings), then we select the `.f.l` widget within that little toplevel, which is the listbox, and then we provide the override for the `font` property, which would otherwise be the default.

Comment: Yes, this stuff is definitely under-documented! And I'd expect `ttk::entry` and `ttk::spinbox` to also use a directly-specified font.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think it would be good if all ttk-widget behave in the same manner. Perhaps this could be an improvement to the next version of tk.

Comment: `option add *TCombobox*Listbox.font namedfont` would be better.  The ttk widgets have a design limitation where only one element within the layout can be addressed.   So most of the options in a ttk::combobox get assigned to the entry box portion and not the popdown.

Comment: The popdown is 90% traditional Tk widget anyway (since there's no `ttk::listbox` widget).